# Unity check if inputfield is equal to a word?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-field

I'm a bit new to Unity, and i just want to know, how can i check if an inputfield is equal to a word or some kind of code, or what i specify?

I tried whith something like:

```
if(inputfield == "Money")
```

but i didn't see it working:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call the text portion of it

```cs
if (inputfield.text == "Money")
```

Comment: Yes as this gentleman says, you need to access the text property. Each UI element in Unity has a number of properties you can access, keep that in mind should you need access to another.

Comment: How can i check, if the player types something else in the inputfield?

Comment: @kalip Something specific? You would do the same way. There's also functions to check if the text field has changed.

Comment: @DylanLawrence I did it, i'm trying to figure out how can i open the mobile keyboard, once the inputfield is clicked..

Comment: @Kalip I haven't done too much mobile but I think it should just open on its own.

Comment: @dylanLawrence I think that too, but it just doesn't, maybe because of IOS?